# Flash CS4: Font Disappearing

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, fonts, embedding

I have an odd issue while using FlashCS4.

- I have a textfield that, when set to
  STATIC TEXT works absolutely fine, in
  the correct font.
- If I set it to DYNAMIC TEXT, the text
  shows up as Arial or some other
  default on systems where the selected
  font isn't available. It shows up in
  the proper font on systems that have
  the font installed.
- If I set it to EMBED CHARACTERS the
  text doesn't show up at all on ANY
  system, whether the font is installed
  or not.

I have tried embedding the font using the [EMBED] tag in my accompanying AS3 code, and I have the font added to the Library in CS4 as well.

In CS4 I've tried selecting the font for the textfield as both the standard OS Font, as well as the one with the Asterisk next to it, but get the same results both ways.

The library font is set to "export for actionscript" and "on frame 1". The font contains no bold/italic/etc. data, and I'm not using any special styling (other than centering the text).

I don't think it's an issue with the font not being available, otherwise it wouldn't show up when it is set to Dynamic without any embedded characters. It's also strange that it wouldn't show up on the computer that has the font installed.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the particular font I was using was broken somehow. I started using a different version of the font downloaded from a different site, and everything worked normally. I could not detect any errors or corruption in the original font's download. :/

Answer (score 1):

Did you click on "Character Embedding" and selected Uppercase, lowercase, numerals and punctuation.

I've found that his problem occours when only a set amount is selected. This should work without any other embedding code, and should not need any library.

Try having just the dynamic textfield on a new flash file and try that only, it should work.

A good way of seeing if they embedded properly is when you rotate the text field, as un-embedded will not show up.

Also try this: Under publish settings -> Flash tab, set Generate size report, and it will show you the fonts and the characters that have been embedded.

if they're showing up there, there's something else you're doing or not doing that's causing this

Comment: Yep, if I select Upper/Lower/Numerals/Punctuation in the CharacterEmbed button, it doesn't display anything at all. But if I set it to "Don't embed" it will show up (only if the font is preinstalled on the computer). :(

Comment: what did the generate size report say?

Comment: In the font section, it's reporting including pretty much every symbol in the font I'm dealing with (300Kb worth):

CombustionWideBRK            302915     !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿˆ˜–—‘’‚“”„†‡•…‰‹›€™

Comment: have you tried it with a different font?
Also, have you tried doing just the text field in a new document, to see if there's anything interfering?

Comment: I just tried it with Arial and it works fine. I tried removing my [EMBED] of the Combust font to see if that was interfering, and I tried using the embedded Combust* and the standard system Combust as well, to no avail. What could be interfering?